# Drupal as a simple file manager

Tags: 7

I'm wondering how easily it would be to achieve the following.

- I want to create a Drupal site where users have a small "file area" to upload files.
- I would like to be able to take those files and upload them to another server (using FTP, HTTP posts, or XMLRPC).
- It would be also nice to get the "remote server" directory listing.

I obviously think this can be easily achieved by ftp; but can I tell to the FTP manager to use the username/password couple of the Drupal user? How can I hide those information to the end user?

What I have in mind is the implementation in Drupal of the Dropbox service, where the Drupal site would be the Dropbox provider.

Any ideas on where to get started ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) module.

It's a powerful upload manager that requires either [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) or [IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) to work.

It supports per-user upload directories and space quotas, amongst other useful stuff.

As for the XML-RPC, you should take a look at the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module.

Regardless of the path you take, you will definitely need to add some custom code and, to help with that (Drupal 7 only) take a look at the [FileTransfer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--filetransfer.inc/class/FileTransfer/7) class. ([related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-php-class-filetransfer/1185#1185))

Comment: Thank but can it handle browsing files that are on different servers than the one where drupal is running ?